# How to change/remove image background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");

dark.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const body = document.body;
  body.classList.toggle("ddark")
})
```

```css
.ddark {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://simg.nicepng.com/png/small/13-133407_pixel-heart-png-black-pixel-heart-icon-png.png" alt="" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
<button class="darkmode" id="dark">Go Dark</button>
```

How can i change or remove image background color? Because when I go dark mode at my website it looks so ugly. How can i fix this? What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SVG images, they change background color according to your background color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Pictures in this format are a whole with their backgrounds. you need to use svg format image for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The image has to be transparent for that to work  - or you need a transform

You can use emojis and pseudo classes instead

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");
const body = document.body;
const imgSpan = document.querySelector(".imgSpan")
dark.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.classList.toggle("ddark")
  imgSpan.classList.toggle("ddark")
})
```

```css
.imgSpan::after {
  content: ""
}

.imgSpan.ddark::after {
  content: "❤️";
}

.ddark {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<span class="imgSpan"></span>
<button class="darkmode" id="dark">Go Dark</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pick an image its background is transparent. Not only SVG, it can be png as well. I took your JPEG edited on https://pixlr.com/x/#editor and removed its background it works.

BTW, why don't you just use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) for such an image.

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");

dark.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const body = document.body;
  body.classList.toggle("ddark")
})
```

```css
.ddark {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/hFFVFdC/hearth-transparent.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
<button class="darkmode" id="dark">Go Dark</button>
```

Comment: Why FA? ❤️ ? Just use normal fonts

Comment: Let's say choice and FA become industry standard. There are ♥ nice☺discussions about this☻on the net•

Comment: Unicode IS already industry standard :)

Comment: , I just find FA icon sett better fitting for most of the web apps. It's search page also has good semantic way of filtering.